# how to I use a string template in my QueryCommand object

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

String templates don't seem to work for me when I set them as a property value in the QueryCommand object. I also cant set the property value to a param

Heres my code

```
const queryItems = async (tableName, pKey, pKeyValue) => {
  const command = new QueryCommand({
    KeyConditionExpression: `${pKey} = #${pKey}`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
//THIS `#${pKey}` BELOW IS THE ONLY PART NOT WORKING
      `#${pKey}`: {S : pKeyValue}
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {"#data":"data"},
    ProjectionExpression: "account_id, info_type, #data",
    TableName: tableName,
  })
  const response = await client.send(command);
  console.log(response.Items);
  return response;
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Reason I don't hard code the partition key is because I want to use this same function on multiple tables.

EDIT: ANSWER. Figured out solution I was indeed overcomplicating things

```
const queryAccountItems = async (tableName, pKey, pKeyValue) => {
  const command = new QueryCommand({
    KeyConditionExpression: `${pKey} = :pKey`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":pKey": {S : pKeyValue}
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {"#data":"data"},
    ProjectionExpression: "account_id, info_type, #data",
    TableName: tableName,
  })
  const response = await client.send(command);
  console.log(response.Items);
  return response;
}
```

Comment: You should change this to the one I suggested. If you pass in a pkey which is a reserved key word you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
KeyConditionExpression: "#pk = :pk",
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":pk": {S : pKeyValue}
    },
ExpressionAttributeNames: {"#pk": pKey, "#data":"data"},
```

Don't over complicate it. If you are using the document client change ExpressionAttributeValues to this:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":pk": pKeyValue
    },
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is then I cant pass the partition key as a parameter in the function, so I would need a new function for every table with a different schema. However this comment did make me realize the answer to my problem which I will add now as an edit.

Comment: My solution does allow you to use different key names and values, and is a valid solution to your question. #pk and :pk are just variable holders.

Comment: Ahh I see, your solution does work. I jumped the gun in saying it doesn't. Thank you for your help.